# Vue becoming unresponsive after removing items in a v-for while using IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I am looping through an array, and each item that is displayed has a click handler to remove that item from that list. After removing 2 items from the array, the whole page becomes unresponsive. This only occurs when while using IE11, there are no problems when using chrome. I cannot figure out what is causing it to become unresponsive.

Here are the code snippets that I am using:

HTML:

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="item.itemId">
     <p>{{item.name}}</p>
     <button @click="removeItem(index)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
removeItem: function(index) {
    this.itemList.splice(index, 1)
}
```

I have also tried filtering the array,and replacing it using slice, but it becomes unresponsive no matter what. Any help would be great.

Edit: I figured it out, there was an arrow function within another method, that was causing it to break while using Ie11. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the `itemList` a large array? Does it also happen when the IE devtools are closed?

Comment: no, the largest it will get would be about 10 items

Comment: A more natural way to remove the items would be by `itemId`, e.g. `this.itemList = this.itemList.filter(i => i.itemId !== itemId)` does that solve the problem? Whenever I see `splice`, that gives me pause - there are a host of bugs you can get in that case because the array will be re-indexed.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible CodePen? The cause could also be anywhere else in your code..

Comment: @DavidWeldon I tried using filter but the same problem occurs. I am able to delete 2 items, and everything become unresponsive

Comment: Interesting. I'd recommend reproducing just that code in a pen, or in another project and see if it suddenly goes away. Maybe something else is going on that's getting triggered by this interaction.

Comment: @Nazgul You should probably use a polyfill for arrow functions. Then, this won't happen anymore 

Comment: @Nazgul, From your update in the original post, we can see that you had solved your issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and  try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.